# Google Tag Manager data layer variable coming through as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm using JQuery to push data layer variables when Ajax is called.  Full script that I'm using is here:

(function() {

```
'use strict';
var $;
var n = 0;
init();

function init(n) {

  // Ensure jQuery is available before anything
  if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {

    // Define our $ shortcut locally
    $ = jQuery;
    bindToAjax();

  // Check for up to 10 seconds
  } else if (n < 20) {

    n++;
    setTimeout(init, 500);

  }

}

function bindToAjax() {

  $(document).bind('ajaxComplete', function(evt, jqXhr, opts) {

    // Create a fake a element for magically simple URL parsing
    var fullUrl = document.createElement('a');
    fullUrl.href = opts.url;

    // IE9+ strips the leading slash from a.pathname because who wants to get home on time Friday anyways
    var pathname = fullUrl.pathname[0] === '/' ? fullUrl.pathname : '/' + fullUrl.pathname;
    // Manually remove the leading question mark, if there is one
    var queryString = fullUrl.search[0] === '?' ? fullUrl.search.slice(1) : fullUrl.search;
    // Turn our params and headers into objects for easier reference
    var queryParameters = objMap(queryString, '&', '=', true);
    var headers = objMap(jqXhr.getAllResponseHeaders(), '\n', ':');

    // Blindly push to the dataLayer because this fires within GTM
    dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'ajaxComplete',
      'attributes': {
        // Return empty strings to prevent accidental inheritance of old data
        'type': opts.type || '',
        'url': fullUrl.href || '',
        'queryParameters': queryParameters,
        'pathname': pathname || '',
        'hostname': fullUrl.hostname || '',
        'protocol': fullUrl.protocol || '',
        'fragment': fullUrl.hash || '',
        'statusCode': jqXhr.status || '',
        'statusText': jqXhr.statusText || '',
        'headers': headers,
        'timestamp': evt.timeStamp || '',
        'contentType': opts.contentType || '',
        // Defer to jQuery's handling of the response
        'response': (jqXhr.responseJSON || jqXhr.responseXML || jqXhr.responseText || '')
      }
    });

  });

}

function objMap(data, delim, spl, decode) {

  var obj = {};

  // If one of our parameters is missing, return an empty object
  if (!data || !delim || !spl) {

    return {};

  }

  var arr = data.split(delim);
  var i;

  if (arr) {

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      // If the decode flag is present, URL decode the set
      var item = decode ? decodeURIComponent(arr[i]) : arr[i];
      var pair = item.split(spl);

      var key = trim_(pair[0]);
      var value = trim_(pair[1]);

      if (key && value) {

        obj[key] = value;

      }

    }

  }

  return obj;

}

// Basic .trim() polyfill
function trim_(str) {

  if (str) {

    return str.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');

  }

}
```

})();

Everything is working for the most part when I'm checking in the console:

**data layer image**

[image]

But when I preview it with in GTM, it's coming up as undefined:

**start date**

[image]

Can anyone guide me so that the correct value shows up? The event triggering it is called ajaxComplete.

Comment: How did you config the variable?

Comment: Do you use dot notation to get values of dataLayer variables?

Comment: I configured a data layer variable in GTM as attribute.startDate and startDate.

Comment: or would I use queryParameters.startDate?

Comment: I'm passing data to the data layer correctly and set up multiple dot notations but when viewing in GTM preview mode, it shows up as undefined.